# nodejs and socket.io chat rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to create chat rooms dynamically with socket.io ? All the examples I've seen so far had every room declared implicitly. I am looking to achieve something like http://tlk.io/ where you simply create a chat room by accessing a random url, and then allow users in based on certain criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. socket.io has a rooms feature.

From the readme:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('justin bieber fans');
  socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
  io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
});
```

Comment: i know it has support for rooms, i am interested in making N number of rooms based on different criteria.How do I make the difference between connecting to such different rooms ?

Comment: I don't know if socket.io allows you to look at the `req` easily. So, send a message from the client to the server asking to join a room.

Comment: I was going to -1 for justin beiber, then i saw rammstein :P

Comment: @DeaDEnD Thanks a lot for your awesome answer. I have the sample chat example running on my system http://socket.io/demos/chat/
However, can you please point me to a direction, how do I make the chat to work so that 2 users randomly connect to each other each time they come on the website? Like Omegle. How can I do something like this?

Comment: Create rooms that only 2 people can be in